# How to dynamically link webkit in Qt

Tags: qt

I have linked to webkit in my .pro file as below

```
QT       += webkit
```

It used to work fine till yesterday, but after a bunch of edits to the .pro file while adding another library, I started encountering crashes from inside Qt's QWebView code. This part used to work fine earlier.

Also a post-build error `QWidget: Must construct a QApplication before a QPaintDevice` led me to this post which says webkit needs to be dynamically linked.

How do I dynamically link webkit in Qt?

Comment: Dynamic linking is the default with Qt. Are you currently statically building your application?

Comment: I've been using the default dynamic build. However, it seems I might have mistakenly edited something elsewhere which has forced it to become static. How do I tell?